# Showing error while adding SendGrid from Masrket Place

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one web app on my azure with Pay-As-Go subscription. I am now trying to add SendGrid from Azure market place. Where deployment job shows me below error. Can you please me for the same.

At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see the link : http://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)

User failed validation to purchase resources. `Error message`:

> '{"ErrorDescription":"The market on the billing account does not match the market on the user account","CultureInvariantErrorCode":"BadRequest","ActivityId":"ab226daf-80cd-418d-bad5-b6be89abcbbb"}' (Code: ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed)

Comment: I am trying to add SendGrid app which is free so that is also not an problem.

Answer (score 0):

After azure support help explanation I found the resolution.

Under “Account Information” page on datamarket.azure.com set US timezone & Azure Account is set as India Region.

Because of the time zone difference its shows me the error. After changing US timezone to IST timezone everything worked perfectly.

May this will help someone who face same problem.